# Save textarea to MySQL and preserve line breaks

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql-injection

Imagine a blog or cms system (PHP and MySQL). I want to let the user enter some text in a textarea and save it to the database. The type of the field in the database is TEXT.

I want to preserve line breaks and print them later. I know I can do this with PHP's `nl2br`-function, but how do I protect this string against SQL-injection attacks (let's assume I can't use prepared statements). If I use `mysql_real_escape_string` on it, it does not show me line breaks anymore.

```
$text = 'one line
another line';
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
/* save to db, fetch it some time later */
echo nl2br($text); /* output: one line\r\nanotherline */
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't *remove* line breaks, it *escapes* them.

It should work okay to escape the string when storing it, and applying `nl2br` (possibly in combination with `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent users from entering raw HTML) when the data is **output**. That's the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_real_escape_string` will replace your carriage return with `\r\n`, hence you will need to get it back using `str_replace()`. However, it still won't be visible in your browser / email client. That's where `nl2br()` comes into play:

```
$text = 'one line
another line';
echo nl2br(str_replace("\\r\\n","
", mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $text )));
```

The code is tested, you can use it.

Answer (score -2):

> If I use mysql_real_escape_string on it, it does not show me line breaks anymore.

don't you see `"\n"` literals in place of line breaks?
if so, your code doing some nasty things, most likely you escape your data twice.
or, don't you do mysql_real_escape_string() after getting data from database?

Anyway, you've got to do some debugging - an investigation, to see what happens to your data on **every stage**. Just print out $_POST['textarea_name'], SQL query, etc.
To see the moment you lose your breaks and to find out an offender

Notes:
mysql_real_escape_string do not protect anything from any attack. It escapes delimiters.
nl2br do not preserve anything. It adds an HTML tag to line breaks.